# Is there a way to prevent js from caching in drupal 8?

Tags: javascript, caching, drupal, drupal-8

I am currently working on a module that requires some js work.
I'm sick and tired of flushing the caches.
I've done everything it says in https://www.drupal.org/node/2598914

Now it seems that only js is caching.

Comment: disable the cache module which are their in Drupal 8 Internal Dynamic Page cache, Internal Page cache

Comment: also check if you have enabled the aggregate JS option in Admin->Config-> Performance

Comment: None of the above seems to work.

Comment: last options if you have done everything above, also clear your browsers cache, cookies once then try again